# Install Gnome-Shell theme without gnome-tweak-tool?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, theme

I've just installed fedora 17 and `gnome-tweak-tool`, but it crashes everytime and I can't change the theme. Any other way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [dconf-editor](http://shuffleos.com/791/dconf-editor-show-selected-app-icons/) or in terminal.

- Install `gnome-shell-extension-user-theme` (if you haven't already).
- Enable `gnome-shell-extension-user-theme`:

*dconf-editor*: expand `org > gnome > shell` then edit the value field for the `enabled-extensions` key, adding `'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com'`to the existing elements (if any)

alternatively, in *terminal*, run:

`gnome-shell-extension-tool -e user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com`

- Then enable your shell theme (e.g. `Adwaita Sky`):

*dconf-editor*: expand to `org > gnome > shell > extensions > user-theme` and change the value for the `name` key to `Adwaita Sky`

or, in *terminal*, run:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "Adwaita Sky"`

A shell restart might be required after these operations: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> >> <kbd>r</kbd>

Comment: I found `gnome-shell-extension-tool` to be the easiest and most effective method